# How android decides which string file to load for locale?

Tags: android, string, locale

My question is, in "Android Source Code" where (in which java file: [Android Source Code](https://github.com/android/)) this decision is being taken of whether load default `strings.xml` or `strings.xml` from `values-ar`, `values-fr` etc?

Answer (score -1):

It taken from the string.xml according to the Locale you set in application. If you set locale as 'en' it select the default string.xml. If you set locale as 'ar' it will set arabic locale and select values from values-ar string.xml file.

You can set the Locale by:

```
Locale locale = new Locale("ar");
Locale.setDefault(locale);
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.locale = locale;
getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

Comment: Okay, but in android source code where this decision is being taken whether to load resources from values-ar/string.xml or from values/string.xml from an apk or from framework-res.apk etc.

Comment: @bappi48 You can set the locale in Onresume or oncreate method according to the need. When you set this, automatically taken the values from corresponding String.xml file.